# Does the community policy allow having several accounts for a single user?

Tags: discussion

I wonder if a policy allows a user register several accounts in stack exchange? Isn't it treated as a reputation cheating mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

A user registering multiple accounts is particularly discouraged. However, some people may accidentally create multiple accounts, and those accounts can be merged when identified.

If you feel someone has abusing multiple accounts for nefarious purposes (like reputation sockpuppeting) please flag the posts with a custom flag and explain as much as possible, preferably with links if you've identified the culprits. From there, we can leverage mod tools to confirm the abuse and take appropriate action.

Comment: For further reading: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682). Also, might be worth to state this too: "*There are a handful of legitimate reasons to maintain multiple accounts. A good rule of thumb for identifying abusive socks is: **if the second account allows you to do something on the site that your normal account would be prevented from doing, it is abuse.***"

Comment: @AndrewT. I completely agree. However, if I had to categorize them, I'd say the vast majority of duplicates are accidents, and the next biggest slice of the pie are sock puppets. The legitimate duplicate users would rarely, *rarely* be identified and/or flagged as such.